# Change words with Firestore trigger onCreate

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Im trying to use a Firestore trigger to change words, when sending a message.
This is my first time working with Firestore, and can't seams to figure it out.

I have a Firestore database that stores messages. A message have:

- Name
- Message
- Timestamp

I would like to change the message to something else, on creation.

One of the things I have been trying is this:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
exports.badWords = functions.firestore
    .document('messeges/{messegeID}')
    .onCreate(event => {
        var data = event.data.data()

        return data.ref.update({
            message: "The message has been changes"
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the `ref` property of the event [`DocumentSnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot?authuser=0), as follows:

```
exports.badWords = functions.firestore
    .document('messeges/{messegeID}')
    .onCreate((snap, context)  => {

       return snap.ref.update({
            message: "The message has been changed"
        });
    });
```

Note that with Cloud Functions version >= v1.0.0 the callback function has two parameters (`snap` and `context`), see https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff#cloud-firestore.

In case you are using a version < v1, you should update your SDK for Cloud Functions to the latest version, by running the following in the functions folder:

```
npm install firebase-functions@latest --save
npm install firebase-admin@latest --save-exact
```